# Read arithmetic operator in postfix notation with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am working on postfix calculator to read <strike>operators</strike> arithmetic operators. An example input is `24 5 6 * +`.

This code read `*` and `/` operators but not read `+` and `-` operators:

```
while(scanf("%d",&temp))
    ARRAY[i]=temp;
scanf("%s",&operator);
```

Comment: What if `scanf` fails and returns `-1` ? this will still be true and you will save some garbage in temp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - Reading arithmetic operators with sscanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246910/c-reading-arithmetic-operators-with-sscanf)

Comment: `scanf("%c",&operator);` if `operator` is defined as a plain `char`

Comment: what is an `operator`? Is it a character array? If yes then omit `&` from second `scanf`

Comment: Even `scanf(" %c",&operator);` with a space to ensure the previous `newline` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` and `-` characters could be the beginning of a number like "+3" or "-1". So code that is looking for a number will consume those characters. Don't use code to read a number unless you are certain you want to read a number and anything that's not a number is an error.