# Map variable-length string to int

Tags: c, string, int, arrays

I can't figure out how to write a function that takes the following input and produces the following output:

```
in (int) | out (char *)
0        | ""
1        | "a"
2        | "b"
3        | "c"
4        | "aa"
5        | "ab"
6        | "ac"
7        | "ba"
8        | "bb"
...
```

It is not simply converting the input to ternary, as there is a difference "a" and "aa" (whereas there is no difference between `0` and `00`).

I have found a correlation between the length of the string and the input (`len = floor(log2(in + 1))`, when you only use `a` and `b`:

```
in (int) | floor(log2(in + 1)) | out (char *)
0        | 0                   | ""
1        | 1                   | "a"
2        | 1                   | "b"
3        | 2                   | "aa"
4        | 2                   | "ab"
5        | 2                   | "ba"
6        | 2                   | "bb"
7        | 3                   | "aaa"
8        | 3                   | "aab"
```

What's the general correlation between the length of the output and the input value, given there is `n` different valid characters?

Comment: actually complication  is introduced by `""` empty string otherwise it would be base4 representation.(*not* ternary)

Comment: If it were a representation of base 4, then "aa" would map to 0 or 5, not 4. This seems like a more complex problem.

Comment: Is it base3 representation when neglecting `""` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to, but distinctly different from, [Calc cell convertor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7651397/).  This code was swiftly derived from that code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* These declarations should be in a header */
extern char     *b3_row_encode(unsigned row, char *buffer);
extern unsigned  b3_row_decode(const char *buffer);

static char *b3_encode(unsigned row, char *buffer)
{
    unsigned div = row / 3;
    unsigned rem = row % 3;
    if (div > 0)
        buffer = b3_encode(div-1, buffer);
    *buffer++ = rem + 'a';
    *buffer = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

char *b3_row_encode(unsigned row, char *buffer)
{
    if (row == 0)
    {
        *buffer = '\0';
        return buffer;
    }
    return(b3_encode(row-1, buffer));
}

unsigned b3_row_decode(const char *code)
{
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned r = 0;
    while ((c = *code++) != '\0')
    {
        if (!isalpha(c))
            break;
        c = tolower(c);
        r = r * 3 + c - 'a' + 1;
    }
    return r;
}

#ifdef TEST

static const struct
{
    unsigned col;
    char     cell[10];
} tests[] =
{
    {    0,      "" },
    {    1,     "a" },
    {    2,     "b" },
    {    3,     "c" },
    {    4,    "aa" },
    {    5,    "ab" },
    {    6,    "ac" },
    {    7,    "ba" },
    {    8,    "bb" },
    {    9,    "bc" },
    {   10,    "ca" },
    {   11,    "cb" },
    {   12,    "cc" },
    {   13,   "aaa" },
    {   14,   "aab" },
    {   16,   "aba" },
    {   22,   "baa" },
    {  169, "abcba" },
};
enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]) };

int main(void)
{
    int pass = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        b3_row_encode(tests[i].col, buffer);
        unsigned n = b3_row_decode(buffer);
        const char *pf = "FAIL";

        if (strcmp(tests[i].cell, buffer) == 0 && n == tests[i].col)
        {
            pf = "PASS";
            pass++;
        }
        printf("%s: Col %3u, Cell (wanted: %-8s vs actual: %-8s) Col = %3u\n",
               pf, tests[i].col, tests[i].cell, buffer, n);
    }

    if (pass == NUM_TESTS)
        printf("== PASS == %d tests OK\n", pass);
    else
        printf("!! FAIL !! %d out of %d failed\n", (NUM_TESTS - pass), NUM_TESTS);

    return (pass == NUM_TESTS) ? 0 : 1;
}

#endif /* TEST */
```

The code includes a test program and a function to convert from string to integer and a function to convert from integer to string.  The tests run back-to-back conversions.  The code does not handle the empty string as zero.

Sample output:

```
PASS: Col   0, Cell (wanted:          vs actual:         ) Col =   0
PASS: Col   1, Cell (wanted: a        vs actual: a       ) Col =   1
PASS: Col   2, Cell (wanted: b        vs actual: b       ) Col =   2
PASS: Col   3, Cell (wanted: c        vs actual: c       ) Col =   3
PASS: Col   4, Cell (wanted: aa       vs actual: aa      ) Col =   4
PASS: Col   5, Cell (wanted: ab       vs actual: ab      ) Col =   5
PASS: Col   6, Cell (wanted: ac       vs actual: ac      ) Col =   6
PASS: Col   7, Cell (wanted: ba       vs actual: ba      ) Col =   7
PASS: Col   8, Cell (wanted: bb       vs actual: bb      ) Col =   8
PASS: Col   9, Cell (wanted: bc       vs actual: bc      ) Col =   9
PASS: Col  10, Cell (wanted: ca       vs actual: ca      ) Col =  10
PASS: Col  11, Cell (wanted: cb       vs actual: cb      ) Col =  11
PASS: Col  12, Cell (wanted: cc       vs actual: cc      ) Col =  12
PASS: Col  13, Cell (wanted: aaa      vs actual: aaa     ) Col =  13
PASS: Col  14, Cell (wanted: aab      vs actual: aab     ) Col =  14
PASS: Col  16, Cell (wanted: aba      vs actual: aba     ) Col =  16
PASS: Col  22, Cell (wanted: baa      vs actual: baa     ) Col =  22
PASS: Col 169, Cell (wanted: abcba    vs actual: abcba   ) Col = 169
== PASS == 18 tests OK
```

Comment: OP wants to go the other way, from `int` to a string.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Oops — you were correct.  I've rewritten my answer completely.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I actually need it both ways, but OK :P

Comment: @Tyilo: And since my code encodes numbers as an appropriate string, and converts a string to the corresponding number, what's the problem?  You call `b3_row_encode()` to convert a number to a string; you call `b3_row_decode()` to convert a string to a number.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I hadn't read the code at the time, so I assumed you had removed the other function ;)

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track: each N-character group is just the N-digit numbers of base M, where M is the number of symbols. So your sequence is the 0-digit ternaries (""), followed by the 1-ternaries ("a", "b", "c"), etc.

The number of digits given the rank is `floor(log3(2n+1))`, and the first rank of each sequence is `(3**d-1)/2`. So the 10000th in the sequence has 9 digits; the first 9-digit sequence ("aaaaaaaaa") is number 9841. 10000-9841 is 159, which in base 3 is 12220, so the 10000th sequence is "aaaabccca".

Answer (score 1):

This simple code works in both of your example cases, and should work if you increase the number of characters that you're using. Here's the easy version in C#:

```
string Convert(int input)
{
    char[] chars = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

    string s = string.Empty;
    while (input > 0)
    {
        int digit = (input - 1) % chars.Length;
        s = s.Insert(0, chars[digit].ToString());

        input = (input-1) / chars.Length;
    }

    return s;
}
```

In C it's a little more complicated:

```
char* Convert(int input)
{
    char* chars = "abc";
    char result[50] = "";
    int numChars = strlen(chars);
    int place = 0;

    // Generate the result string digit by digit from the least significant digit
    // The string generated by this is in reverse
    while(input > 0)
    {
        int digit = (input - 1) % numChars;

        result[place] = chars[digit];

        input = (input-1) / numChars; 
        place++;
    }

    // Fix the result string by reversing it
    place -= 1;
    char *reversedResult = malloc(strlen(result));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= place; i++)
    {
        reversedResult[i] = result[place-i];
    }
    reversedResult[i] = '\0';

    return reversedResult;
}
```

Comment: Which dialect of C are you using?

Comment: Haha, the sharp variety I guess. Sorry, it wasn't mentioned in the question except in the tag. Consider it pseudocode for now.

Comment: OK — for the time being, your C♯ code is considered pseudo-code.  I recommend adding appropriate comments, or a C natural (C♮) version of the code, or both, but you should be given time to fix it before you get flattened (C♭) with down-votes.

Comment: Your C (natural) code works — naturally. My direct transcription of your C# code into C was different—no `malloc()`: `static char *Convert(int input) { static char s[32]; char chars[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; s[0] = '\0'; while (input > 0) { int digit = (input - 1) % sizeof(chars); size_t len = strlen(s) + 1; memmove(s+1, s, len); s[0] = chars[digit]; input = (input-1) / sizeof(chars); }  return s; }` It could be improved (for example, it could track length rather than calling `strlen()`; it should be made reentrant by passing the buffer to the function instead returning the static array, etc.)

Comment: It has been years since I've written anything in C. Guess it's showing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not simply a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, multiplied by 3^n where n is the position in the string? It seems like a slightly weird definition of ternary. The empty string is equivalent regardless of how long the empty string is because anything besides a, b, and c contributes 0 to the output value.

Furthermore, the two tables in your question seem to conflict. In the first table, 5 --> "ab" while in the second table 5 --> "ab." Is that intentional? If so the function is not one to one and your question is much more murky.

Comment: the first table is with three possible characters "abc" and the second table is with only two possible characters "ab".

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.